# clamav cl_scanfile takes a long time to finish

Tags: php, security, cakephp, file-upload, antivirus

How to optimize clamav cl_scanfile so it is faster? On average It takes about 15-20 seconds for scanning the file. Thus if in one form I have 2 upload field, it will take almost 40 seconds or more, which will cause php max execution time error.

I would rather not change the execution time of php.

Is there anyway to do this?

My code will be something like this:

```
function upload() {
...
        // Checking element type based on element id.
        // if element type == file, check the file type. Based on the result, halt (redirect to failure) or continue
        foreach ($this->_controller->data['FormSubmission'] as $elementId => $fieldValue) {
...
...
                        //Checking The File for Virus
                        $retcode = cl_scanfile($fieldValue["tmp_name"], $virus_name);

                        //if Virus not found
                        if ($retcode != CL_VIRUS) {
                            //Check Directory if uploadPath is not a directory, make it
                            if (!is_dir($uploadPath)) {
                                mkdir($uploadPath, 0777, TRUE);
                            }

                            //filename
                            $now = date('Ymd-His');
                            $fileName = $now . '-' . $elementId . $fieldValue["name"];

                            $fullFilePath = $uploadPath . '/' . $fileName;
                            $uploading = move_uploaded_file($fieldValue["tmp_name"], $fullFilePath);
                            // change the value to uploadPath for ul/dl
                            $this->_controller->data["FormSubmission"][$elementId] = $fullFilePath;
                        } else {
                            //If Virus found, don't upload anything
                            $this->_controller->data["FormSubmission"][$elementId] = "";
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the time down by 1/2 by adding
`clamav.load_db_on_startup=1` to `/etc/php5/mods-available/clamav.ini`

```
extension=clamav.so
[clamav]
clamav.dbpath="/usr/local/share/clamav"
clamav.load_db_on_startup=1
clamav.maxreclevel=16
clamav.maxfiles=10000
clamav.maxfilesize=26214400
clamav.maxscansize=104857600
clamav.keeptmp=0
clamav.tmpdir="/tmp"
```

Still takes around 7-8 seconds, depending on the file size.

http://php-clamav.sourceforge.net/parameters.php#load_db_on_startup

Answer (score 0):

I would not consider myself to be an expert in Clam AV, but my understanding is that there is not any way to optimize the call for each file, unless you can eliminate some of the signature database (which in many cases you cannot).  If you know for example, that the file will never be used on a Windows system, you could eliminate the Windows signature DB, saving substantial time.  Be careful with this though, as it can backfire.  It might be preferable though to changing the PHP timeout value, which I agree you shouldn't do.

Clam AV uses a multi-threaded daemon however, so another thing you can probably do to optimize is run each file scan concurrently (multi-threaded or multi-processed).  This won't help much for small quantities of large files, but it could make a big difference for large quantities of small files.  This is the approach I would take.  There's [a great post on PHPlens covering parallel processing in PHP](http://phplens.com/phpeverywhere/?q=node/view/254).  You can also use [an open source Pthread library for PHP](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads).  It's available on Github under user Krakjoe.

Answer (score 0):

default ubuntu clamav (sudo apt-get install calmav) comes compiled with mpi- so speed up things with:

`sudo mpirun -np $(grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo) clamscan -r --bell -r /`

still takes a while, but give it a shot

Answer (score -1):

Tip: ClamAV is not a traditional anti-virus or endpoint security suite. For a fully-featured modern endpoint security suite, check out Cisco Secure Endpoint. See "related products", below, for more details.

https://docs.clamav.net/